# Comparing Multiple Strings Using Logical Operator Is Not Working Properly in C Programming

Tags: c, if-statement, logical-operators, c-strings, strcmp

I am trying to **check if the user string input** (after lowercasing user input) **matches with required three strings** i.e. *rock* or *paper* or *scissor*. If it doesn't match the requirement the system will print *It is a wrong input*. Otherwise, I'll do something.

> When I'm giving only **one check without the logical || operator, it is working fine** i.e. comparing the user input string with the required one. But when I'm **using logical operator it is not working properly** i.e. if I give right keyword, it is saying that it is a wrong input.

Being a beginner I couldn't figure out the possible reason after searching in StackOverflow also. Any help in advance. Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char game[40];
    printf("Enter one among rock, paper and scissor: ");
    scanf("%s", &game);
    for (int i = 0; game[i]; i++)
    {
        game[i] = tolower(game[i]);
    }
    if ((strcmp(game, "rock") == 1) || (strcmp(game, "paper") == 1) || (strcmp(game, "scissor") == 1))
    {
        printf("You entered a wrong input\n");
    }
    else
    {
        /* Doing Something */
    }
    
}
```

Comment: After reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp , what return value do you expect from `strcmp()` for "identical"?

Comment: @Yunnosch for identical it'll return 0 and for different it'll return 1. So I'm here trying to get 1 - if that's the case then the user input is wrong.

Comment: " for different it'll return 1" Nope. For different it will return positive or negative.

Comment: Oh...yes...but I changed those to !=0 ... but the problem remains same

Comment: I think asking a separate new question on your changed code is appropriate. Do not edit this one to invalidate existing answers please.

Comment: @Yunnosch ok sir...thank you for pointing out

Answer (score 2):

Read The Friendly Manual: `man strcmp`

> The strcmp() and strncmp() functions return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1 (or the first n bytes thereof) is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.

That is, in case the strings match, `strcmp` returns 0.

So to check if something is *not* a match, De Friendly Morgan says that we should do:
`a!=0 AND b!=0 AND ...`.

Answer (score 1):

From the description of the function `strcmp` in the C Standard *7.23.4.2 The strcmp function)

> 3 The strcmp function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or
> less than zero, accordingly as the string pointed to by s1 is greater
> than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by s2.

That is the function can return any integer number greater or less than zero in case when strings are not equal each other. If two strings are equal each other then the function returns 0.

So rewrite the if statement

```
if ((strcmp(game, "rock") == 1) || (strcmp(game, "paper") == 1) || (strcmp(game, "scissor") == 1))
{
    printf("You entered a wrong input\n");
}
```

the following way

```
if ( strcmp(game, "rock") != 0 && strcmp(game, "paper") != 0 && strcmp(game, "scissor") != 0 )
{
    printf("You entered a wrong input\n");
}
```

That is when the entered string is not equal to all of the required strings.

Pay attention to that instead of

```
scanf("%s", &game);
           ^^^
```

you have to write

```
scanf("%s", game);
           ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
if ((strcmp(game, "rock") == 1) || (strcmp(game, "paper") == 1) || (strcmp(game, "scissor") == 1))
```

to

```
if ((strcmp(game, "rock") != 0) && (strcmp(game, "paper") !== 0) && (strcmp(game, "scissor") != 0))
```

Comment: I have tried that also as if they are same that will return 0...but the problem remains same as I mentioned habove

Comment: @AdrijaRoy check updated answer does this work